# Get Values from table rows on button click jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get row values from a table on button click. This is how I created the table:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        ViewBag.AccountID = item.AccountId.ToString();
        if (item.Items != null)
        {
            foreach (var itemOnList in item.Items)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => itemOnList.ItemId)</td>
                    <td data-itemname="@itemOnList.ItemName">@Html.EditorFor(model => itemOnList.ItemName)</td>
                    <td data-serialnumber="@itemOnList.SerialNumber">@Html.EditorFor(model => itemOnList.SerialNumber)</td>
                    <td data-brandname="@itemOnList.BrandName">@Html.EditorFor(model => itemOnList.BrandName)</td>
                    <td data-quantity="@itemOnList.Quantity">@Html.EditorFor(model => itemOnList.Quantity)</td>
                    <td data-description="@itemOnList.Description">@Html.EditorFor(model => itemOnList.Description)</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);"  data-itemid="@itemOnList.ItemId" class="btn_edit">Edit |</a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-itemid="@itemOnList.ItemId" class="btn_delete">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    }
</tbody>
```

This is how I try to get the values from the table:

```
$('#tbl_items').on('click', '.btn_edit', function () {
    var self = $(this);
    alert($(this).data('serialnumber') + " " + $(this).data('description'));
});
```

but it doesn't alert me the values.

Comment: If you're not already, I'd recommend debugging using console.log() and the subsequent developer tools of whatever browser you're using, instead of alerting the lines to debug (or both, depending on if the alert is part of your desired functionality). That way you can understand why a problem may be occurring when an error is thrown (in this instance, there must be an error somewhere because as you've said, no alert occurs). add console.log($(this).data('serialnumber') + " " + $(this).data('description')) before the alert and see what error is thrown in the browsers developer tools...

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because the `data-serialnumber` and `data-description` attributes are not on the `a` element you click, they're on `td` elements in the same row.

To fix this you can use `closest()` to get the nearest `tr`, then find the `td` and get the `data` attribute values, like this:

```
$('#tbl_items').on('click', '.btn_edit', function () {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var serialNumber = $tr.find('td[data-serialnumber]').data('serialnumber');
    var description = $tr.find('td[data-description]').data('description');
    alert(serialNumber + " " + description);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this to us. I'll mark this answered after 7 minutes.